# Should the reporter have used the definite article "the" before the phrase "old wine"

Tags: articles, american-english, definite-article, zero-article

As we know, *wine* is an uncountable noun in English. I was reading the news and in the news the reporter has used the phrase "old wine". Being an Indian everyone knew that the reporter was talking about **Narendra Modi (the Prime Minister of India)**. So my question is, should the reporter have used the definite article *the* before the phrase "old wine".

In the news

> To his critics, though, much of this is **old wine** in a new bottle, minor cosmetic tweaks that betrayed no signs of the paradigm shift in India’s destiny that Modi promised.

As per my opinion:

> To his critics, though, much of this is **the old wine** in a new bottle, minor cosmetic tweaks that betrayed no signs of the paradigm shift in India’s destiny that Modi promised.

Comment: You don't give a link to the source, but I see no reason to think it's not written by a native speaker. Why do you (presumably *not* a native speaker) think the word ***the*** should be included? As a native speaker myself, I can assure you that article would be a strong indicator of NNS status. Personally, I'd normally expect *neither* article *(["much of this is old wine in new bottles"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22much+of+this+is+old+wine+in+new+bottles%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl))*

Comment: @FumbleFingers English is not our first language in India. I also notice some mistakes in Indian newspapers, novels etc. Should I read newspapers and novels of the USA and the UK to avoid these mistakes or is it okay to continue with them?

Comment: I know that at least *some* things that look like "mistakes" to US/UK Anglophones are actually "normal/correct" in Indian English, so it's a job for me to say. Though I doubt the presence or absence of either of those articles is related to IE as such. But I should also point out that there are subtle nuances whereby either or both articles can "reasonably" be included (though doing so precludes the possibility of using the idiomatically more common "uncountable wine + plural new bottles").

Comment: ...to expand on just one such nuance, in ***the** old wine in new bottles*, I understand ***the*** as being an ***explicit*** reference to the clichéed old saying. Somewhat akin to *"old wine in new bottles, **as the saying goes**"*. That's to say when we ask *which particular wine* are we supposed to understand ***the*** as referencing, the answer is it's the wine in the saying. But normally we just *use* the saying - we don't simultaneously call attention to the *fact* that we're using it.

Comment: Aw...you still practice *As per my opinion!*

Comment: Some interesting traits of InE: frequent sentence-final *also* and *only*, *wh-* and polar questions without subject-auxiliary inversion, frequent use of *as per*, syllable-timed pronunciation, stative verbs used freely in the progressive, use of the perfect instead of simple, use of transitive verbs intransitively, use of *isn't it* as an invariant form, and certain vocabulary (e.g. *prepone, a doubt, do the needful*).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, *wine* is **not always** uncountable. It's a *[count noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wine?q=wine)* as well.

> *For other cheesy dishes, a light, fruity red wine is sometimes better.*

Now the sentence in concern.

*Old wine in new bottles* is **the** idiom, as pointed out by FF. And, it is used *as it is* without any article. [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) gives 13 results with exactly those words. On the other hand, *the old wine in a new bottle* and *the old wine in new bottle* returns no result.

If you search for *old wine in a new bottle* on Google News, the results are mostly from the Indian Dailies. I think it's common here in InE or probably in AsE.

Comment: About the only way I can think of to use 'the old wine in a new bottle' is if a dinner host offered me a choice between an old wine in a new bottle, and a new wine in an old bottle. I could say 'I'd like the old wine in a new bottle, please'.
Using 'the' means 'specific wine', which you and I either know about, or are specifying now.

Comment: @SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher: Per my last comment to the question, we all *know* the "original", so it's quite natural to read [*just **the** same old wine in a new bottle*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22just+the+same+old+wine+in+a+new+bottle+and%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) as both a ***reference*** to "that" wine *and*  a ***use*** of the [slightly adjusted] saying. In OP's specific context it's also reasonable to switch from plural to singular *a new bottle* in order to emphasise that Modi is just one man/one party (that maybe doesn't represent/encompass *all* Indians).